# How to associate a name to a password in Python txt file?

Tags: python

I have a txt file that have this data: 
`Randy Orton|RKO@gmail.com|rko2000|
Undertaker|Taker@gmail.com|deadman21|
Triple H|Thegame@gmail.com|HHH3|`

I want to login a user with your password, but when I type a user name any password in the file allow the user to login. How can I fix this?

Example: I type "Undertaker" as user name. But in the password if I type "HHH3" ("Triple H's" password) I can login. But I want to allow only a user with his correct pass.

```
print("Consultar Gastos")

   while True:

       file = open("Moradores.txt", "a+")
       file1 = open("Moradores.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

       lerFile = file1.readlines()

       mLogin = input("Login: ")

       if mLogin not in lerFile:
           while True:
               print("Name not registered, try again")
               mLogin = input("Login: ")
               if mLogin in lerFile:
                   break

       mPass = input("Password: ")

       if mPass not in lerFile:
           while True:
               print("Wrong Password, try again")
               mPass = input("Password: ")
               if mPass in lerFile:
                   break
```

Comment: can't realy understand what you are trying to do, could you post a more complete code and explain more?

Comment: I changed some things, I'm sorry if you can't understand clearly, my english and programing skills is not so good. Can you understand now?

Comment: You are just checking if the password is contained in the file. You need to find the row associated with the username entered and extract the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you need to parse the file (in this case `Moradores.txt`) for usernames and passwords and store this data in some data structure (in my example in `dict`):

```
# parse the users file for usernames and passwords:

users = {} # <-- we will store the users in this dictionary

with open("Moradores.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        user, email, password, _ = line.split('|')
        users[user] = (password, email)

print("Consultar Gastos")

mLogin = input("Login: ")

while True:
   print("O nome não está cadastrado, tente novamente")
   mLogin = input("Login: ")
   if mLogin in users:  # <-- change
       break

mSenha = input("Senha: ")

while True:
   print("Senha incorreta, tente novamente")
   mSenha = input("Senha: ")
   if mSenha == users[mLogin][0]:   # <-- change
       break
```

Note: You can `print(users)` to see, how the dictionary looks like.

Comment: To add to what @Andrej Kesely said, switch the 'e-mail' and the 'user' (make e-mail the key of your `dict`). Doesn't make much of a difference here since wrestler names will most likely always be unique, but as a general rule, you want to choose the **most** unique *thing* for your keys, which in this case is the e-mail.